# Can not read properties of undefined (reading mimetype) in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, csv, file

I am trying to upload a csv file using angular, i am using  node as backend.When i am trying to upload the file using postman and hitting the node js endpoint it is working fine. But when i am trying to upload the file using the frontend using angular then i am getting the error

```
 cannot read properties of undefined(reading mimetye)
```

I am giving the code what i am using

node.js

```
class UploadController{
   uploadCsv = async(req,res,next)=>{
   console.log('i am in controllr');
   console.log(req.file.mimetype);
  try{
      if(req.file==undefined){
      return res.status(400).send("Please upload a csv file!");
     }
     await FileService.uploadCSV(req,res);
     return res.status(200).send({
      message: 
       "Uploaded the file successfully: "+req.file.originalname
   });
})
```

Angular Code

```
 uploadmyFile(fileUpload:File){
   const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type':'text/csv',
   Authorization: `Bearer ${this.userDetails.token}`,
   user_id : this.userDetails.user_id,
   }),
   params: new HttpStatus({
    fromObject :{
     user_id: this.userDetails.user_id,
   },
   }),
  };
let fromData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileKey', fileUpload,fileToUpload.name);
return this.http.post<any>(
 'http://localhost:3000/upload?file',
 formData,
 httpOptions
  );
}
```

I am assumming there  is problem with the angular code , reason is node is working perfectly when trying to upload file from the postman.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab of the console? And there is a typo in your code: ```let fromData.....``` and then your post contains ```formDate```

Comment: @CharlieV Internal Server Error i am getting

Comment: In the Angular client you're attaching the file under `fileKey`, in NodeJS you are accessing it via `req.file`. Could this be it?

Comment: changing to file also not working

Answer (score 0):

Your header should specify multipart:

```
{"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"}
```

and your code:

```
let formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileUpload,fileToUpload.name);
return this.http.post<any>(
 'http://localhost:3000/upload?file',
 formData,
 httpOptions
  );
}
```